# How to interpret the S-parameters of this result?

Tags: rf, antenna

I'm designing an FSS in CST MWS that should be providing maximum reflection for the band (12 to 15)GHz and hence minimum transmission to this band. I've got the results has shown here. How do I find the return loss and transmission loss? Out of these 8 data legends like SZmax(2),Zmax(2), which are the return loss (S11) and transmission coefficient (S21)? By transmission coefficient, forward transmission coefficient is meant. Floquet port model is used.
Fig.1 S-parameter output
Fig.2 CST port illustration
[image: S-Param]
[image: CST Port]

Comment: What is FSS? In the first forth of the first line there are already three non-trivial abbreviation. The last two is related to a commercial software product. This site is not about how to use a given product, but to build a general knowledgebase.

Comment: I'm new to this forum. FSS stands for frequency selective surface and CST MWS is Computer Simulation Technology (Microwave Studio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the CST MWS help page on FSS, it is mentioned that the reflection is specified using SZmax(1),Zmax(1) while the transmission is specified using SZmin(1),Zmax(1). When the magnitude of the reflection is greater than the transmission by a fair margin, then the designed FSS is said to function as a ground plane for the designed band.

Comment: Welcome :-) This topic is outside my area of expertise so I can't help with the question, but I'm confused about the question's status. You have written in the box labelled "Your Answer". Therefore if this really is your full answer to your question, meaning that the topic can be closed, then please "accept" your answer (green tick) and the topic will be effectively closed. However, if you are just adding new information and your question is not answered, then this is the wrong place for you to write it. Instead edit the question, add the new info there and delete this "non-answer". Thanks.

Comment: I'll. The suggestions are noted. :-)